# Show that a closed path is homotopic to a constant path

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\delta$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2-\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a path joining $0$ to $\infty$ which is injective, i.e., it is a simple path, it does not intersect itself. Show that $\delta$ is homotopic to a constant path in $(\mathbb{R}^2-{0})$. I am assuming the path are defined on the interval $[0,1]$.

Here, homotopic means that there is a continuous application from $\delta$ to the constant path, with fixed extremities, i.e. I should be able to crunch $\delta$ to a point without moving one of its point which we will assume to be $\delta(0)=\delta(1)$ (since $\delta$ is closed). Also, obviously, the crunching should not involve an intermediary path crossing $0$.

This means, assuming the paths are parametrized on the interval $[0,1]$, that I should be able to find a continuous application $H$ from $[0,1]^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2-0$ such that $H(0,t)=\delta(t), H(1,t)=\delta(0), H(s,0)=\delta(0)=H(s,1)$ (this last double equality encodes fixed extremities, 
 the $H(s,t)$ are intermediary paths which should continuously go from $\delta$ to the constant path)

A hint is given, telling me to consider $\delta(t)-\alpha(s)$, but I don't know what to do from here, since it does not even fix extremities and goes to infinity. It does not intersect $0$ though, which is a good thing at least. What can I pick for $H$ that will work for any path $\delta$? If its interior is convex then this is easy, but otherwise this can become complicated...

Comment: Just a note : by Jordan's theorem, there is a homotopy in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\alpha$ as well (though I'm not sure you're allowed to used that theorem)

Comment: @Max I shouldn't be using this theorem, anyway this is obvious even from a cursory  glance that a plane without a branch from $0$ to $\infty$ is simply connected. I think I am supposed to give an explicit formula using $\delta(t)-\alpha(s)$ for $H$. I've been on it for hours, and this is a question from an old exam that's supposed to last 2 hours. I'll have to sit for this exam in a week. I wish I were dead, I made a tragic mistake by picking a geometry class this year. The profs there simply brush everything off as "obvious from a glimpse", but us students are not held to the same standards.

Comment: As stated, this isn't true (if $\alpha$ intersects itself, it may not even be connected !), but its connected components will be simply connected indeed.

Comment: @Max Yes, thank you, here it is implied that $\alpha$ is injective, i.e., it does not intersect itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly give a homotopy $H$, but the argument is at least elementary.  Consider, as in the hint, the family of loops $$\gamma_s: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}, \quad t \mapsto \delta(t) - \alpha(s)$$ for $s \in [0, \infty)$.

Since $\alpha(s) \to \infty$ and the image of $\delta$ is bounded, there exists $S \geq 0$ such that $\lvert \alpha(S) \rvert > \lvert \delta(t) \rvert$ for all $t$.  I claim that the degree of the map $\gamma_S: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \simeq S^1$ is zero.  If not, then for some $t$, $\delta(t) - \alpha(S)$ must be perpendicular to $\alpha(S)$, i.e., $0 = \langle \delta(t) - \alpha(S), \alpha(S) \rangle = \langle \delta(t), \alpha(S) \rangle - \lvert \alpha(S) \rvert^2$.  But by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $\lvert \langle \delta(t), \alpha(S) \rangle \rvert \leq \lvert \delta(t) \rvert \cdot \lvert \alpha(S) \rvert < \lvert \alpha(S) \rvert^2$ for all $t$ by our choice of $S$.  So indeed $\deg \gamma_S = 0$.

Now, the function $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{Z}$, $s \mapsto \deg \gamma_s$ is locally constant.  Since $[0,\infty)$ is connected, we deduce that in particular $\deg \gamma_0 = \deg \gamma_S = 0$.  Since $\gamma_0 = \delta: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, this means that there is a homotopy from $\delta$ to a constant path in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I probably misinterpreted the hint.